# Metadata API not working on sandboxs

Tags: metadata-api, python

I am trying to connect to the metadata Api via a python script. Essentially, I am authenticating into the SOAP Api, getting a session Id, then setting the session if in my Metadata client class. This works well for production orgs but when trying to connect to the metadata api for a sandbox, I keep getting an "invalid session id" error. Perhaps the URL is wrong? If so I cannot figure out how to set it.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Are you using https://test.salesforce.com Or login.salesforce.com url?

Comment: does the user is api enabled and has modify all data permissions in the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

To set uRL you can use below sample code

final LoginResult loginResult = loginToSalesforce(USERNAME, PASSWORD,

private static LoginResult loginToSalesforce(
        final String username,
        final String password,
        final String loginUrl) throws ConnectionException {
    final ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
    config.setAuthEndpoint(loginUrl);
    config.setServiceEndpoint(loginUrl);
    config.setManualLogin(true);
    return (new EnterpriseConnection(config)).login(username, password);
}

from the loginResult you can get the session id.